# How to fix button location at the bottom in ionic

Tags: css, user-interface, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want the button to be set at the bottom, not in the center but the CSS code is not truly effective.

```
<ion-content class="cards-bg social-cards">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-item>
      <textarea #myInput id="myInput" rows="1" maxLength="500" (keyup)="resize()" [(ngModel)]="myStuff" placeholder="post comment"></textarea>
      <button id="mybtn" ion-button outline item-end icon-left>
        <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>
```

CSS

```
.mybtn  {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the button always to be at the bottom regardless of page scroll

Comment: @MaheshJadhav, Thanks for your comment, this is for posting comments text area and I think the button should be near to end line like messengers.

Comment: Ok so basicslly you need something like what messengers have a textarea and  send button next to it for submitting somewhat same as we are commenting right now using stackoverflow comments section right?

Comment: why don't you try using button inside ion-footer section that way it will be always at the bottom of the screen regardless of the device or screen size.i have implemented that code if you want i can share in answer section.

Comment: the comment box is not in the footer it is  relative and placing under the to post below the comment box placing users comments

Comment: I've posted a photo of app.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking for but ever heard of fab button?
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/fab/FabButton/